# windows phone load image from isolated storage in a list

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone page and in it there is a `LongListSelector` tag. in each of it's elements there are some text and an image which coms from isolated storage!

I wanted to know how should i load these images and put the in the list as referencing through Uri is not supported for isolatedstorage!

UPDATE:

the key part of my problem is this: `LongListSelector` is pupulated with bining and I don't know how to put different images in different places. actually I want to update an image which is inside a `LongListSelector`

here is the details code:

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentItems}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged" >                
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                      <Image Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="left" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"></Image>
                  </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

now I want to change the first image in the list with an image from isolated storage dynamically. (for instance by pushing a button)

thanks

Comment: Basically you can refer to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918393/2998271) to load image from isolated storage and display it using Image control (focus on `LoadImage()` function and ignore `else` block there). How to apply that solution in your case depends on how your `LongListSelector` is populated.

Comment: the key part of my problem is this: `LongListSelector` is pupulated with bining and I dont know how to put different images in different places. actually I want to update an image which is inside a `LongListSelector`

Comment: Elaborate more about "*how to put different images in different places*", don't get it clearly. With current information only, I can't suggest anything. Post some relevant codes part (LLS's ItemTemplate, class definition used for LLS's ItemsSource)

Comment: Have you tried data binding?